# LINQ Unpivot a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a table which spreads weekly values into 52 columns, together with Product and Location columns.
E.g.

```
Product|WK-0|WK-1|WK-2|...|WK-52|Location
```

I'm trying to transpose this table into row as such :

```
Product|Location|Week|Value
```

Based on [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11641690/2699762), I created following code :

```
var columns = 53;
var testList =from n in Enumerable.Range(1, columns)
              let c = db.Stock_On_Hand_Files
                        .Where(p => p.Product == "00009E85 " && p.Location == "A_DOMEST")
                        .First()
              select new
              {
                Product = c.Product,
                Location = c.Location,
                Column = n.ToString(),
                SOH = c[n]
               };
```

But I'm getting following error on the last line

> Error  CS0021  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Stock_On_Hand_File'

As requested, schema for Stock On Hand File.

```
    public partial class Stock_On_Hand_File
{
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> PastDue { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_001 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_002 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_003 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_004 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_005 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_006 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_007 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_008 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_009 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_010 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_011 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_012 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_013 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_014 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_015 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_016 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_017 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_018 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_019 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_020 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_021 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_022 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_023 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_024 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_025 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_026 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_027 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_028 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_029 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_030 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_031 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_032 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_033 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_034 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_035 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_036 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_037 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_038 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_039 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_040 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_041 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_042 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_043 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_044 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_045 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_046 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_047 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_048 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_049 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_050 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_051 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> WK_052 { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdateDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of `Stock_On_Hand_Files`?

Comment: That line will generate 53 calls to the DB.. oooooh (the `let` is INSIDE the `from`)

Comment: And you can't access a field by index... In C# it is nearly impossible if you have distinct properties named `Foo1`, `Foo2`, `Foo3` to access them like `"Foo" + ix`

Comment: (unless you use reflection)

Comment: I would make the weeks a list() object or dictionary as follows : Dictionary<string, double> wkDict;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a little reflection, a little caching of the generated delegates:

```
static readonly Func<Stock_On_Hand_File, Nullable<double>>[] Getters = GenerateGetters();

static Func<Stock_On_Hand_File, Nullable<double>>[] GenerateGetters()
{
    var getters = new Func<Stock_On_Hand_File, Nullable<double>>[52];

    for (int i = 0; i < getters.Length; i++)
    {
        var getter = typeof(Stock_On_Hand_File).GetProperty("WK_" + (i + 1).ToString("D3")).GetGetMethod();
        getters[i] = (Func<Stock_On_Hand_File, Nullable<double>>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Stock_On_Hand_File, Nullable<double>>), getter);
    }

    return getters;
}
```

and then

```
var row = db.Stock_On_Hand_Files.Where(p => p.Product == "00009E85" && p.Location == "A_DOMEST").First();

var result = Enumerable.Range(0, Getters.Length).Select(x => new
{
    row.Product,
    row.Location,
    Week = Getters[x](row),
}).ToArray();
```

If you want to pivot multiple "base" rows:

```
var rows = db.Stock_On_Hand_Files.Where(p => p.Product == "00009E85" && p.Location == "A_DOMEST");

var result = from row in rows.AsEnumerable()
             from x in Enumerable.Range(0, Getters.Length)
             select new 
             {
                 row.Product,
                 row.Location,
                 Week = Getters[x](row),
             };
```

Note the use of `AsEnumerable()` to force the second part of the query to be executed locally (and not on DB)

Note that you don't need reflection to do this code... You can do it "manually":

```
static readonly Func<Stock_On_Hand_File, Nullable<double>>[] Getters = new Func<Stock_On_Hand_File, Nullable<double>>[] 
{
                   x => x.WK_001, x => x.WK_002, x => x.WK_003, x => x.WK_004, x => x.WK_005, x => x.WK_006, x => x.WK_007, x => x.WK_008, x => x.WK_009,
    x => x.WK_010, x => x.WK_011, x => x.WK_012, x => x.WK_013, x => x.WK_014, x => x.WK_015, x => x.WK_016, x => x.WK_017, x => x.WK_018, x => x.WK_019,
    x => x.WK_020, x => x.WK_021, x => x.WK_022, x => x.WK_023, x => x.WK_024, x => x.WK_025, x => x.WK_026, x => x.WK_027, x => x.WK_028, x => x.WK_029,
    x => x.WK_030, x => x.WK_031, x => x.WK_032, x => x.WK_033, x => x.WK_034, x => x.WK_035, x => x.WK_036, x => x.WK_037, x => x.WK_038, x => x.WK_039,
    x => x.WK_040, x => x.WK_041, x => x.WK_042, x => x.WK_043, x => x.WK_044, x => x.WK_045, x => x.WK_046, x => x.WK_047, x => x.WK_048, x => x.WK_049,
    x => x.WK_050, x => x.WK_051, x => x.WK_052,
};
```

Comment: Another way: `double?[] GetValues(Stock_On_Hand_File x) { return new[] { x.WK_001, x.WK_002, x.WK_003, ... etc };} ` And then a bit of shuffling around with LINQ (see: `Enumerable.SelectMany()`). Reduces the number of function calls.

Comment: @Vilx That is a very simple and minimalistic solution :-) You should post it.

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
var item = db.Stock_On_Hand_Files
    .Where(p => p.Product == "00009E85 " && p.Location == "A_DOMEST")
    .First();

var arr = new[] { item.WK_001, item.WK_002, item.WK_003, ... continue for all weeks };
var result = arr.Select((x, i) => new
{
    Product = item.Product,
    Location = item.Location,
    Column = (i+1).ToString(),
    SOH = x
});
```

Or, if you want to do it for a whole list:

```
var result = db.Stock_On_Hand_Files
    .Where(p => p.Product == "00009E85 " && p.Location == "A_DOMEST")
    .SelectMany(item => {

        var arr = new[] { item.WK_001, item.WK_002, item.WK_003, ... continue for all weeks };
        return arr.Select((x, i) => new
        {
            Product = item.Product,
            Location = item.Location,
            Column = (i+1).ToString(),
            SOH = x
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way your code would work is if your class had an indexer and your properties were aware of it. For example:

```
public partial class Stock_On_Hand_File
{
    private Nullable<double>[] _weeks = new Nullable<double>[52];

    public string Product { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> PastDue { get; set; }

    public Nullable<double> WK_001 
    {
        get { return _weeks[0]; }
        set { _weeks[0] = value; }
    }

    public Nullable<double> WK_002 
    {
        get { return _weeks[1]; }
        set { _weeks[1] = value; }
    }

    //etc...

    public Nullable<double> this[int index]
    {
        get { return _weeks[index]; }
        set { _weeks[index] = value; }
    }

    //snip
}
```

*Note: This might cause issues if you try to use it with an ORM like Entity Framework...*

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access fields of a class in an index.

So either you

- use reflection to get the value at these fields:
  `(double) c.GetType().GetProperty($"WK_{n:D3}").GetValue(c, null)`
- Or you use reflection to convert to a `DataTable` and then you can access them with the indexer. You can see how to do it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24131656/1375753
- Or you create an `indexer` in the class itself and then use a `switch` or reflection to serve the appropriate value:

  ```
  public double this[int index] 
  {
      switch (index)
      {
          case 1: return this.WK_001
          case 2: return this.WK_002
      }

      // Or: return (double) this.GetType().GetProperty($"WK_{index:D3}").GetValue(c, null);
  }
  ```